# How to implement paypal and amazon checkout service similar to what Louis CK did

Tags: php, paypal

Comedian Louis CK sold his live special on his website (https://buy.louisck.net/).  Visitors can purchase it using Paypal or Amazon.

I'm looking to sell a few music tracks.  How do you implement this functionality in PHP?  I understand you send the user to login to Paypal or Amazon, but how do you get a callback URL that shows the download link?

Comment: Try reading the online documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal has a very well documented [PHP API & IPN](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code)

same is Amazon [PHP SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)

I don't think someone around here will ever write you the code. The main thing about this community is about learning and not getting free stuff!

Good luck on your project, and from my experience you should be able to easily integrate both PayPal and Amazon as they are simple and easy to use.